# Angular JS, Git and Non-Heroku Deployment

Tags: angularjs, deployment

I have Ruby on Rails as my primary programming language and the workflow mostly went as make changes-commit changes-push changes-deploy with capistrano

I looked over the internet for ways to have such a workflow (or at least quite similar) for Angular.JS and I can't seem to find one. There is Yeoman but I can only see examples for Heroku. I host with Webfaction right now.

So I was wondering is there some way to track an angular JS project with Git (preferably Github) then deploy it to Webfaction from that git repo?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I use yeoman to setup angular.js apps and capistrano to deploy them on production (digitalocean) - I wrote an article about this: http://howwedoapps.com/2014/04/03/deploy-angularjs-app-with-capistrano-on-the-cloud. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Webfaction, but if it's a VPS you have take a look at [Dokku](https://github.com/progrium/dokku). 
It's basically your own Heroku, hosted on your own server.

Comment: I checked it out and correct me if I'm wrong but it seems to only work if you have Ubuntu on your VPS. Webfaction has CentOS

Comment: Yes, it's only Ubuntu (at least for the time being)

Answer (score 0):

While it's not specificaly git based, [capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) is one of the most popular ways of deploying ruby web application to a vps. It has features that would allow you to deploy from github, but that would need to be configured separately and would need to be called from the command line from your development computer.